# Flutter problem with async ( Need to execute first GetData and then execute this GetData)

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, final, table-calendar

OKay, i'm having a problem and this is with an async problem. I need to execute a function first after other part of code. Here is the problem

```
Future<void> getData() async {
  User? usuari = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final allDataGlobal = <RegistreSentiment>[];
  CollectionReference collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('usuaris')
      .doc(usuari!.uid)
      .collection('Registre sentiments');

  final registresRef = collectionRef.withConverter<RegistreSentiment>(
    fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) =>
        RegistreSentiment.fromMapData(snapshot.data()!),
    toFirestore: (notaActual, _) => notaActual.toMap(),
  );

  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<RegistreSentiment>> registresUsuari =
      await registresRef.get().then((snapshot) => snapshot.docs);

  registresUsuari.forEach((doc) => {
        allDataGlobal.add(doc.data()),
        // convert this Map to your custom object and add it to your list
      });

  for (var dataRegistre in allDataGlobal) {
    DateTime tempDate = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(
        dataRegistre.dataRegistreTS!.microsecondsSinceEpoch);
    // dataRegistre.dataRegistre = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(tempDate);
    dataRegistre.dataRegistre = tempDate;
  }

  for (var element in allDataGlobal) {
    /*
    print(element.dataRegistre);
    print(element.dataRegistre!.day);
    print(element.dataRegistre!.month);
    print(element.dataRegistre!.year);
*/
    _kEventSource[DateTime(
      element.dataRegistre!.year,
      element.dataRegistre!.month,
      element.dataRegistre!.day,
    )] = _kEventSource[DateTime(
              element.dataRegistre!.year,
              element.dataRegistre!.month,
              element.dataRegistre!.day,
            )] !=
            null
        ? [
            ...?_kEventSource[DateTime(
              element.dataRegistre!.year,
              element.dataRegistre!.month,
              element.dataRegistre!.day,
            )],
            element
          ]
        : [element];

    print(_kEventSource);
  }
}
```

I want to execute this code first and then after this

```
final kEvents = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<RegistreSentiment>>(
  equals: isSameDay,
  hashCode: getHashCode,
)..addAll(_kEventSource);
```

The problem is when i try to add an Event to the calendar it executes first to "add the event" and then executes getData, so that's obvious that it can't get the data and it gives me null. How can i do to execute GetData first after that "kEvents"

Comment: just use `await getData();` to wait until getData completely executed.

Comment: It gives me an error, _HomePage.initState() returned a Future.
State.initState() must be a void method without an 'async' keyword.

Comment: @Albertmoracostillo Based on Hayi Nukamn's answer, you don't need to add an async keyword to initState just do this:

```@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
getData();
}
```

Comment: if you call it on initState, make some other method which call these 2 logic in sequence,  for example: `executeLogic() async { await getData(); final kEvents = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<RegistreSentiment>>( // and so on` Then call this executeLogic method inside `initState` foe example: `@override void initState() { super.initState(); executeLogic(); }` <-- without await.

Comment: The problem is that kEvent is in a different class